# How to install pcre2-tools on Rocky Linux

Tags: linux, regular-expression, yum, pcregrep

I am on RL v9.1. The package seems to be there ([pcre2-tools-10.40-2.el9.x86_64.rpm](https://rockylinux.pkgs.org/9/rockylinux-devel-x86_64/pcre2-tools-10.40-2.el9.x86_64.rpm.html)) but yum doesn't see it:

```
yum install pcre2-tools
runner_gitlab-runner          1.4 kB/s | 1.0 kB     00:00    
runner_gitlab-runner-source   1.4 kB/s | 951  B     00:00    
No match for argument: pcre2-tools
Error: Unable to find a match: pcre2-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

The package you mention is available on the [Devel repo](https://wiki.rockylinux.org/rocky/repo/#notes-on-devel)

The wiki mentions :

> This repository should only be enabled for package building/development purposes and **should not** be permanently enabled.

---

To only install `pcre2-tools` from `devel`, you can use `includepkgs` :

> *includepkgs*
> Include packages of this repository, specified by a name
> or a glob and separated by a comma, in all operations.
> Inverse of excludepkgs, DNF will exclude any package in
> the repository that doesn't match this list. This works in
> conjunction with excludepkgs and doesn't override it, so
> if you 'excludepkgs=*.i386' and 'includepkgs=python*' then
> only packages starting with python that do not have an
> i386 arch will be seen by DNF in this repo.  Can be
> disabled using --disableexcludes command line switch.
> Defaults to [].

1. Enable the repo

```bash
dnf config-manager --set-enabled devel
```

2 : Use your favorite editor to add the `includepkgs` directive

```bash
sudo -e /etc/yum.repos.d/Rocky-Devel.repo
```

In the file, add  :

```bash
includepkgs=pcre2-tools
```

and save

Now, you can install `pcre2-tools`